# How to repack a repository at Github?

Tags: github

I know about the `git repack` command but I can only apply it locally. How can I force the server to adapt the changes?

I want people who clone my repository onto their hard disk to get the optimized repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any user-side command that could trigger a repack on the GitHub side.
You can email GitHub support, asking for a repack, but I suspect they would answer such an administration task is run on a regular basis on all their repo anyway.